# Gmail not rendering non direct link images

Tags: php, html, image, email, gmail

I'm sending HTML formatted email content with my website. It includes a 'tracking image' to track if email has been opened or not.

It goes like this:

```
<img src="http://bgcs.ivankp.xyz/admin/email/logo/a2xvbmVuZ2FuMWFAZ21haWwuY29tfDIz">
```

Upon loading this image, it will tell my website that this email has been opened and then rendering the real image.

But, it seems that it has been erased by Gmail. My image is gone but when I 'Show Original", the link is there.

[image: Original Email Message with img script]

If I try with a direct-link image such as:

```
<img src="http://bgcs.ivankp.xyz/assets/pages/img/email/5951502621018.png">
```

No problem at all.

Any suggestion on how to do this properly?

Comment: Gmail doesn't allow `base64` encoded images. Instead save it to your server and send that link in mail.

Comment: The first img ref you show, and the one in your email screenshot, returns a 404.  That would certainly explain why it does not show up - it does not exist.